# find -exec where filename is not the last parameter

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to pass the files from find command to adb push like this:

```
find . -name "test0[4-8]*.py" -exec adb push {} \; /storage/emulated/0/
```

I get an error
    `find: paths must precede expression: /storage/emulated/0/`

How can I specify that `/storage/emulated/0/` is not a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon indicating the end of the `exec` command should be at the end of the `exec` predicate:

```
find . -name "test0[4-8]*.py" -exec adb push {} /storage/emulated/0/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming /storage/emulated/0/ is the path on the remote device? So it should form part of the command, your \; comes before it.

`find . -name "test0[4-8]*.py" -exec adb push {} /storage/emulated/0/ \;`

if that still gives you issues put "/" for each "/" to escape them. Effectively everything from -exec to \; is sent into a sub shell with {} replaced with the path to each file found.